# Ninject : Pass object down layers through bindings for multitenancy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I have a multitenant application in Asp.NET MVC with Ninject and Fluent nHibernate. I have one Database per tenant and I create one session factory for each tenant.

Now after the tenant logins, I need (if it doesn't exists) create a SessionFactory and get a session out of it. That's done.

My problem now is that the specific tenant info is extracted from the FormsAuth cookie and I need to pass it down layers...

Here are my layers :
Web
Service
Data

When my controllers need to access some info, they use the specific info service to get to the data repository with has a session which come from the sessionfactory.

In **Data Layer** :

```
        Bind<SessionFactoryFactory>().ToSelf()
            .InSingletonScope();

        Bind<ISession>()
            .ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<SessionFactoryFactory>()
                .Get(**[??TENANTINFOOBJECT??]**).OpenSession())
            .WhenParentNamed("TenantDB")
            .InRequestScope();

        Bind<ISomeInfoRepository>()
            .To<SomeInfoRepository>()
            .InRequestScope()
            .Named("TenantDB");
```

In **Service Layer** :

```
        Bind<ISomeInfoService>().To<SomeInfoService>()
            .InRequestScope();
```

In **Web Layer** :

```
public class SomeController : BaseController
{
    ISomeInfoService someInfoService;

    public SomeController(ISomeInfoService someInfoService)
    {
        this.someInfoService= someInfoService;
    }...
```

How do I send to my sessionfactory the tenant info with Ninject? When a web request is made, I extract the tenant id from the cookie and can build the required tenant object (id + connection string). How do I pass it down the layers with Ninject to my SessionFactoryFactory?

Comment: Do you have an access to your Ninject container from your MVC application?

Comment: I do, but I rather not use it as that would not be test friendly. Aside from a NinjectModule for the bindings, the Data Layer do not know about Ninject.

Comment: What exactly would not be test friendly?

Comment: Sorry, I interpreted that you would want to call the kernel from the Data Layer. But I'll let you explain what you had to propose.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to make your SesssionFactoryFactory dependеnt on some ITenantInfo, then re-register this ITenantInfo as a dependency on every request (in terms of per-request scope)

Comment: The more mature solution would be to create child containers for each tenant and just "switch" between them based on the current tenant info from request.

Comment: See [this article](http://whereslou.com/2010/05/05/multi-tenancy-in-aspnet-mvc-with-ioc) and Orchard's codebase for more information

Answer (score 0):

Register a type that is your TenantInfo in the request scope.  This TenantInfo could be created from the cookies using the ToMethod as you are doing in your question.

Then Bind the ISession to a ninject provider (a class which inherits from Provider).  Make this provider take as a constructor argument (or property) the TenantInfo.  Within the provider you then have the necessary information to construct your session. for the Tenant.